# Check if csv file is in UTF-8 with PHP

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

Is there a way which checks a CSV-file for UTF-8 without BOM encoding? I want to check the whole file and not a single string.

I would try to set the first line with a special character and than reading the string and checking if it matches the same string hard-coded in my script. But I don't know if this is a good idea.

Google only [showed me this](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/389742-how-determine-if-file-utf8-encoded). But the link in the last post isn't available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if (mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents($file), 'UTF-8')) {
    // yup, all UTF-8
}
```

You can also go through it line by line with `fgets`, if the file is large and you don't want to store it all in memory at once. Not sure what you mean by the second part of your question.

Comment: This function does not check for bad byte sequence(s), it only checks if the byte stream is valid.

Comment: @Damien I'd be thankful if you could clarify what exactly that means. It catches malformed UTF-8 byte sequences, so what's is a "bad byte sequence" then? http://codepad.viper-7.com/6yvKe9.

Comment: There's a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47990) about this function not catching surrogates in UTF-8, but I [can't reproduce that](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DFz1nJ) anymore.

Comment: An UTF8 bad byte sequence is like \x00\xE3 (two sequence, UTF-32). It's valid UTF-8 but not a valid sequence: �

Comment: @Damien And `mb_check_encoding` catches that just fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FBjzrC

Comment: The test must be run without the backslashes - and the function return a true when testing for UTF-8. Maybe it's enought for @testing? It's a bad UTF-32 sequence still :)

Comment: @Damien Sorry, not following. If you run that without the backslashes, it's just a regular ASCII string and the test is nonsense. And the `\x00\xE3` is indeed not UTF-32, since it's only two bytes long, where it should be at least four.

Comment: I was wrong about the backslashes, failed my tests on the way... sry for the confusion. mb_check_encoding seem's ok then, you'r right.

Comment: And what if the file is too large to fit into memory?

Answer (score 5):

I recommand this function (from the symfony toolkit):

```
<?php
  /**
   * Checks if a string is an utf8.
   *
   * Yi Stone Li<yili@yahoo-inc.com>
   * Copyright (c) 2007 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved.
   * Licensed under the BSD open source license
   *
   * @param string
   *
   * @return bool true if $string is valid UTF-8 and false otherwise.
   */
  public static function isUTF8($string)
  {
    for ($idx = 0, $strlen = strlen($string); $idx < $strlen; $idx++)
    {
      $byte = ord($string[$idx]);

      if ($byte & 0x80)
      {
        if (($byte & 0xE0) == 0xC0)
        {
          // 2 byte char
          $bytes_remaining = 1;
        }
        else if (($byte & 0xF0) == 0xE0)
        {
          // 3 byte char
          $bytes_remaining = 2;
        }
        else if (($byte & 0xF8) == 0xF0)
        {
          // 4 byte char
          $bytes_remaining = 3;
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }

        if ($idx + $bytes_remaining >= $strlen)
        {
          return false;
        }

        while ($bytes_remaining--)
        {
          if ((ord($string[++$idx]) & 0xC0) != 0x80)
          {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

But as it check all the characters of the string, I don't recommand to use it on a large file. Just check the first 10 lines i.e.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("mycsv.csv", "r");
$check_string = "";
$line = 1;
if ($handle) {
    while ((($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) && $line < 11) {
        $check_string .= $buffer;
        $line++;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);

    var_dump( self::isUTF8($check_string) );
}
```