# How check a file is format UTF-8?

Tags: php

I import 1 file csv from client to server. 
Now i want check encode of this file is utf-8.
How check a file is format UTF-8 in php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907196/check-if-csv-file-is-in-utf-8-with-php

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string mb_detect_encoding ( string $str [, mixed $encoding_list = mb_detect_order() [, bool $strict = false ]] )
```

See [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Answer (score 1):

Look here for detecting file encoding in PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php