# Encoding issue - Broken characters

Tags: java, php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Is there a way on `PHP` or `Java` to detect `encoding issues`?.

I mean, sometimes texts are broken, like the content of [this file](https://dropfile.to/0n6tfeP).

As you can see on the image below. The Notepad++ has some black characters with a code inside. That's because he noticed it was a problem there.

I would like to detect this on `PHP` or `Java`, so I can make a bulk replace on that file to a replacement UTF-8 character.

This is part of a big problem. I just simplified it a the lowest.

On the HxD hex editor (used encoding `ANSI`) you can see that this characters are (in hex): 93 and 94.

On the Notepad++ (used encoding `UTF-8`) you also get these codes with a black background.

I would really need to find a way to detect where are these broken characters.

If you know about other way to achieve this detection using another program that let me make the bulk replace, that would work for me.

With `Notepad++` I cannot even search for that text. I mean, it show you up the issue, but if you copy that character and look for it on `Notepad++` you cannot make the replacement.

On PHP there is a function that detects if the text is correct: `mb_check_encoding`, but it doesn't let me to do a replacement.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907196/check-if-csv-file-is-in-utf-8-with-php)

[image]

Comment: `The Notepad++ has some black characters with a code inside. That's because he noticed it was a problem there.` --> that is not true. Notepad++ shows you what the bytesequence mean in the currently selected character set.

Comment: but Notepad++ shows you that because there was a problem there (broken character). If the character is ok, then Notepad++ will show you the right character.

Comment: As you can see in your other screenshot (presumably of the same file) the character is not broken. It's just not an ASCII character. Telling Notepad++ with which encoding to read the file will fix your problem.

Comment: I downloaded your file and just opened in Notepad++. See screenshot: https://dropfile.to/gFBo7NK

Comment: Because Notepad++ is showing you the file with ANSI encoding. Click on: Encoding / Encode in UTF-8. This will show you the document with UTF-8 encoding which is the encoding I'm interested on.

Comment: Assume that string is part of an UTF-8 text, then, of course it would be broken. I would need to detect that situations and make replacements of those broken characters.

Comment: when you opened the file with Notepad++ it guessed its encoding was ANSI, but I say you that the encoding is UTF-8

Comment: Now I understand your problem. Check the methods offered in the `Characters` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/Characters.html

Comment: HxD editor shows that the file encoding is ANSI (not UTF-8). [As you can see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), bytes `0x93` (decimal 147) and `0x94` (decimal 148) in _Orange cells with a large dot are **continuation bytes**_. Open file as ANSI and then you can `Convert to UTF-8` from `Encoding` menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.